# Как узнать размер файла внутри торрент-файла средствами C#?

Tags: c#, файлы, torrent

Как можно узнать размер файла (фильма), находящегося внутри торрент-файла средствами C#?

Comment: это подходит https://gist.github.com/ttrider/bde3ebf5e7af6cd2b5ee ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй с использованием библиотеки [BencodeNET](https://github.com/Krusen/BencodeNET)

```
TorrentFile torrent = Bencode.DecodeTorrentFile("ИМЯ_ФАЙЛА");

string infoHash = torrent.CalculateInfoHash();

// Получить название, размер, полный путь файлов торрента списком.
BList files = (BList)torrent.Info["files"];
foreach (BDictionary file in files)
{
    // Размер файла в БАЙТАХ
    long size = (BNumber) file["length"];

    // Полный путь файла, разбитый на директории
    BList path = (BList) file["path"];

    // Название последнего элемента в пути файла
    BString fileName = (BString) path.Last();

    // Перевод fileName в string
    string fileNameString = fileName.ToString(Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32067409/decode-bencode-torrent-files)

Comment: Большинство библиотек, выложенных на гитхабе, можно использовать через nuget. Не надо при этом себе скачивать исходники https://www.nuget.org/packages/BencodeNET/

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39539/discussion-on-answer-by-ddevil---------).